# C# How to make a smooth jump in unity3d without moving the X, towards the nearest object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I would like to make a smooth jump towards the nearest cube. I already have a script to detect the closest cube. I want that the X-axis is locked, so only the Y-axis and the Z-axis change when jumping. I would like to use a Jump animation when jumping. I already tried to use Vector3MoveTowards, but that didn't really work well, maybe I didn't use it properly.

**Detect nearest cube where the player should jump to (C#)**

```html
void Update()
{
  FindClosestCube ();
  GameObject closestCube = FindClosestCube ();
  Debug.Log (closestCube);
}

GameObject FindClosestCube() {

  GameObject[] gos;
  gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("cube");
  GameObject closest = null;
  float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
  float position = transform.position.z;
  foreach (GameObject go in gos) {
   float diff = go.transform.position.z - position;

   float curDistance = diff;
   if (curDistance < distance) {
    closest = go;
    distance = curDistance;
   }
  }
  return closest;
 }
```

The tricky part is that at some cubes you have to jump up (y+1), with some cubes you jump towards the same Y (y+0) and with some cubes you jump down (y-1).
How do I do this?

**Image of how it looks like:**

[image]

EDIT: I have this code right now:

```html
 ----------------C#-----------------

    Rigidbody rb;
 public int clicks = 0;
 Vector3 target;
 public Animation jumpAnimation;
 bool jump = false;
 float cubeDiffY;
 bool movePlayer;
 public float smoothTime = 0.3f;
 public float yVelocity = 0.0f;

 void Start()
 {
  rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
 }

 void Update () 
 {
  FindClosestCube ();
  GameObject closestCube = FindClosestCube ();
  Debug.Log ("Closestcube = " + closestCube);     

  target = closestCube.transform.position + new Vector3 (0f, 0.7f, 0f);

  cubeDiffY = target.y - transform.position.y;
  movePlayer = true;

  Debug.Log("Cube Difference Y-axis = " + Mathf.Round(cubeDiffY));

  if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
  {
   clicks += 1;

   jump = true;
   jumpAnimation = gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>();
   //jumpAnimation.Play ();
  }

  if (jump == true) 
  {
   Jump ();
  }
 }

 void Jump()
 {

  float newPosition = Mathf.SmoothDamp (transform.position.y, target.y, ref yVelocity, smoothTime);
  transform.position = new Vector3 (0, newPosition, transform.position.z);
 }
```

I calculated the difference in Y-axis between the cube where the player is standing on and the closestCube. But the Jump() doesn't work. How do I fix that?

Comment: These cubes are all in different `x/y/z` locations. You can't possibly jump between them without modifying `x`.

Comment: This isn't a programming problem as much as it's a physics problem. If you want the player to jump to the nearest cube and the position of where the next cube relative to the player is without a pattern, you would have to take the starting point and the destination point, and calculate the force vector that would cause the player to perform that arc.

Comment: A way I can see to possibly simplify the issue is to use the starting point and destination point to construct a 3D bezier curve path that the game will then use to translate the cube over an amount of time.

Comment: Brandon Ibbotson sorry you are right. I forgot to mention that the cubes are moving in x-axis. They move like this: https://i.gyazo.com/e10f09aa103227c097aef1b36e16b613.gif

Comment: Abion47 but how should I calculate that? I have no idea..

Comment: To determine whether or not the next cube is higher or lower, youll have to get the difference on the y axis from the current cube to the next cube. i dont know if you're directly translating the "player" cube or using a rigidbody and addforce to push it, but you will have to program according to the difference of the y axis.

Comment: I would simply try using AddForce (on the y and z axis) on the player cube. Use the difference in height between the player and the next cube in order to scale the force you will add up or down. A little trial and error should get you the right values.

Comment: Following @Abion47 i'd recommend looking [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/407480/rocketscience-how-to-find-out-what-force-is-needed.html), [there](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/408636/help-with-calculating-grenade-projectile-trajector.html) or around [this thread](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/trajectory-calculations.98598/).

Comment: @StevenMills, GarrenFitzenreid, stuck on the easiest part ^^ calculating the difference in heigt. I got this: http://pastebin.com/PeVen2ua. I know I am doing something wrong but I don't know what. ''NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Player.Update () (at Assets/Player.cs:28)
''

Comment: Pastebin page randomly removed, new one: http://pastebin.com/gbwtLU34

Comment: I fixed the calculating the difference in Y-axis between the cube where the player is standing on and the closest cube.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I set up a quick version of your game and got what you wanted to work, it is not exactly a quick solution, because what your doing doesn't have built in functionality for other than using animations.

Here is the character script that has all the code you need and commented thoroughly so it should explain itself.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    //the collider for the player
    private new BoxCollider collider;

    //the jump box collider on a empty game object that is a child to the player object
    public BoxCollider JumpBox;

    //the offset of the cube so it doesn't stop inside of it
    public Vector3 cubeOffset;

    //how high the jump will be
    public float JumpHeight;

    //how fast the jump will be
    public float JumpSpeed;

    //holds the change in position the jump will produce
    private Vector3 jumpDelta;

    //holds the destination cube the jump is attempting to hit
    private Cube destinationCube;

    //true if a jumping animation is currently playing
    private bool jumping = false;

    //used to swap the jump direction from up to down
    private bool jumpDirection = true;

    //used to hold the position of the jump so it knows when to stop
    private float jumpPosition = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        collider = GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(jumping)
        {
            //move straight towards the cube
            transform.position = transform.position + (JumpSpeed * jumpDelta);

            //move up and down to simulate a jump
            //check the current move direction
            if (jumpDirection)
            {
                //add to the jump position twice product of the JumpHeight the JumpSpeed so that it will 
                //rise and fall the same amount of time it takes to move to the destination
                jumpPosition += JumpHeight * JumpSpeed * 2;
                //if it has passed the jump height reverse the jump direction
                if (jumpPosition >= JumpHeight)
                    jumpDirection = !jumpDirection;
                transform.position += transform.up * JumpHeight * JumpSpeed * 2;
            }
            //the jump direction is going down
            else
            {
                jumpPosition -= JumpHeight * JumpSpeed * 2;
                transform.position -= transform.up * JumpHeight * JumpSpeed * 2;
            }
            //check if the character collider intersects witht he cubes collider
            //if it has then stop jumping and set the final position as the destination position
            if (collider.bounds.Intersects(destinationCube.BoxCollider.bounds))
            {
                jumping = false;
                transform.position = destinationCube.transform.position + cubeOffset;
            }
        }
        //detect a jump
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            //detect all hits on the jump box
            Collider[] hits = Physics.OverlapBox(JumpBox.center, JumpBox.size * 0.5f);
            //get the closest collider with the right tag
            Collider result = GetClosestColliderWithTag(hits, "Cube");

            //if we have a result then begin the jumping animation
            if(result != null)
            {
                //gets the destination cubes cube component(the custom class you have on your cubes)
                destinationCube = result.gameObject.GetComponent<Cube>();

                //calculate the jump delta
                jumpDelta = (result.transform.position + cubeOffset) - transform.position;

                //remove the left and right components so the jumping doesnt move to the left or right of the player
                Vector3 component = Vector3.Project(jumpDelta, -transform.right);
                jumpDelta -= component;
                component = Vector3.Project(jumpDelta, transform.right);
                jumpDelta -= component;

                //setup the jump animation control fields to the initial values
                jumpPosition = 0;
                jumpDirection = true;
                jumping = true;
            }
        }
    }
    private Collider GetClosestColliderWithTag(Collider[] colliders, string tag)
    {
        //just gets the closest collider
        float distance = float.MaxValue;
        int result = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
        {
            if (colliders[i].tag == tag)
            {
                float distanceTemp = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, colliders[i].transform.position);
                if (distanceTemp < distance)
                {
                    distance = distanceTemp;
                    result = i;
                }
            }
        }
        if (result != -1)
            return colliders[result];
        else return null;
    }
}
```

And here is my cube script which has some things you will need to add

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Cube : MonoBehaviour {
    //these arent important just fields I used to set up a quick version of your game
    public GameObject StartPoint;
    public GameObject EndPoint;
    public float Speed;
    private Vector3 directionVector;
    private bool direction;

    //YOU WILL NEED THIS!!
    [HideInInspector]
    public BoxCollider BoxCollider;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
        //not important
        directionVector = EndPoint.transform.position - StartPoint.transform.position;
        directionVector.Normalize();

        //DONT FORGET TO SET YOUR BOX COLLIDER
        BoxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float distance = 0;
        if (direction)
        {
            distance = Vector3.Distance(EndPoint.transform.position, transform.position);
            transform.position += directionVector * Speed;
            if (distance < Vector3.Distance(EndPoint.transform.position, transform.position))
                direction = !direction;
        }
        else
        {
            distance = Vector3.Distance(StartPoint.transform.position, transform.position);
            transform.position -= directionVector * Speed;
            if (distance < Vector3.Distance(StartPoint.transform.position, transform.position))
                direction = !direction;
        }
    }
}
```

**Previous Answer**

I would say you need to calculate the perceived position of the object in the future.

```
Vector3 futurePos = cubePos + (cubeMoveDirection * cubeMoveSpeed);
```

Once you have the future position, even if it is not exact, you should aim your animation towards that position. To do this I would have the animation change a speed vector instead of an actual transforms position that way we can rotate this speed vector in any direction you want while keeping the orientation of the block. Otherwise you have to rotate the entire block to point towards the direction you want. If this is what you want then put your block under a empty gameobject, rotate the empty gameobject to point to where you want and do the speed calculations only.

Next your animation should have a net move vector which should be pre-calculated and scaled down or up to meet the distance to the future position. It will look something like this(note this is not tested)

```
//class fields
Vector3 AnimatedSpeed;

Vector3 AnimationDelta;

//basic calculation

//get the direction vector from the players current position to the future 
block position

Vector3 dirVector = futurePos - transform.position;
//find the rotation from the current orientation to the direction vector
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.forward, dirVector);

//calculate the distance from you to the cube and scale it with the magnitude of the AnimationDelta
float result = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, futurePos);

result = result / animationDelta.magnitude;

//finally rotate the forward vector by the rotation and multiply it by the 
//animation speed and the result to get the step by step movement as
//the animation plays. NOTE: The animation should be based on forward direction

transform.position += (AnimationSpeed * rotation) * result * Time.deltaTime;
```

Hopefully this does it, like I said I haven't tested it at all so you may have to do some tweaking based on your particular case as this is essentially psuedo-code.

Good luck! I'm off to bed I'll check back when I wake up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't understand some of the things you said: ''calculate the perceived position of the object in the future.'' I already got a script to calculate the closest cube every frame. Isn't that the same? ''aim your animation towards that position.'' I want to make it like the x-axis  doesn't change. Only by standing on a moving cube. So the animation should keep the same x-axis, only the Y and Z should change. But why wouldn't I use smoothdamp for the y? and lerp for the z?

Comment: I called it perceived position of the object in the future because it is assuming the cube will not change speed to it is just a guess. But you basically are doing a lerp with the code I put you can modify it to do a smooth step if you want. Wont be too much extra code

Comment: If you just want the player to jump forward then all it is is scaling the z jump height to the height of the nearest cube, which the above code can be modified to do that. Its just about picking and choosing which axis you change and how you set up your animation. Try to think about it this way. What do you want the y axis to move like, what do you want the z axis to move like? Focus on one at a time.

Comment: I took a look at the code but it's a bit confusing to me and i'm not sure if this is what I want. The animation is not necessary, it's just an addon. Maybe I can use Vector3.MoveTowards, but the problem is that it is moving in a straight line to the nearest cube, so it's going to crash in the side of the cube. I would like to have the MoveTowards to move in a curve (arc) so it lands on top of the nearest cube. I tried to found an answer for that but couldn't reallt find an answer. Maybe you know how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Hey man sorry  have not responded yet I had to work 12 hrs all weekend and now doing some errands but once I get home and get on the computer I will work up a solution if you still need it. I will test and make sure it works before showing you. Just let me know if you still need help.

Comment: Alright, well despite you not getting back to me and letting me know you still need help I will begin working on it. The way, I understand you want it, is The player cannot jump side to side, but just forward, the only thing you have to worry about is how high the player needs to jump according to the closest block. One thing I am going to change is have a box collider to represent the jump box, or the area in which the player can jump to, that way you can make sure the character doesn't jump to a cube the player did not attend to.

Comment: Alright I am finished, of course as always you will need to change it depending on how your exact game is but everything you need to create a scripted jumping animation is there. Really hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: sorry for not responding, also busy. I will take a look at the code and try it out if im home!

Comment: some things are confusing to me.. maybe you can help via teamvierwer if you want? My skype is Jip1912

Comment: Well I sent you a message on Skype, is there anything specific you are confused about?

Comment: im confused about the fact that I asked how to have a vector3.movetowards with a curve, but you sent me something really different with a lot more than I expected, which is ok and thank you for the effort but I don't know how to use it because I expected something else. Btw. I haven't got a skype message yet.

Comment: You wanted a jumping animation, which is not just moving towards something correct? I know programming can get confusing but the trick is not to look at it like a bunch of code, all it is is a set of step by step instructions. Try to look at my code one line at a time and figure out what it is doing and why. I need to know what exactly confuses you on what that code is doing or I will not be able to clear it up!