# How to have a Vector3.Movetowards with a curve in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to have a Vector3.Movetowards with a curve in Unity3D? MoveTowards is going in a straight line to the target but I want it to move in a curve (arc).

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Well I made a thread about jumping but I only had this question left. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41417905/c-sharp-how-to-make-a-smooth-jump-in-unity3d-without-moving-the-x-towards-the-n
This is my full code: http://pastebin.com/FYQ2h0Bw

Comment: So you want your player to jump and the jump should look like a curve?

Comment: look into that: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/simple-jump-script.82983/

Comment: i think you should provide more details on your question, is it jumping? projectile? movement forward? yours is too broad. make it specific

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka but they don't use MoveTowards. I want to use that.

Comment: @Tengku Sorry, nornally I do. My player (a cube) has to jump to the nearest cube. Sometimes it has to jump y+1, or y+0 or y-1. I already have a script that calculates the nearest cube and the differen in y axis between the nearest cube and the cube where the player is standing on. I send a link in the comments in here where you can see an image I can post an inage here if I am home.

Comment: so the question is, do you want it to be curve jumping to the nearest cube ? or something else?

Comment: @Tengku Yes, curve jumping to the nearest cube. I updated the question with an image.

Comment: The easiest way would be combining `MoveTowards` with adding force to rigid body of the cube. add rigidbody component use `AddForce()`. since you attach rigidbody, there will be gravity for default. unless you disable it.

Comment: @Tengku I think that addforce doesn't really work for this or I do something wrong. I add this line: rb.AddForce (transform.up * SpeedUp);
Let's say I put SpeedUp to 10, it will still not be curved but only a bit higher and it will hit the side instead of the top. When I do something like 30, it will fly up really high. Gravity is enabled.

Comment: Ok I had a little idea to make a vector 3 between the currenCube and the nearestCube with a larger Y-axis and if the playerCube reaches that, it will go to the nearest cube so that the playerCube makes a sort of detour so it looks like a curve. I made this: http://pastebin.com/GESjHE1e But the first half of the jump the player is acting normal but after that, it's going really slow: https://i.gyazo.com/0fb06abbeb825890b3918ca5a0f7f54b.gif There should be an easier way to do this. Also the X-axis shouldn't change when jumping,

Answer (score -1):

If you are making your game in 2022 you can use splines that are new on 2022 version and you can make the cube follow that trajectory

Hope It's good for you